# Passing a macro to an environment option (TikZ/pgfplots)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros, expansion

My particular question involves TikZ/pgfplots (see MWE below) but I suppose a more general solution exists (or does not exist for a deep reason that I could not find).

I wish to predefine some value and pass it later on in the options of an environment (in my case, the `xtick` or/and `xticklabels` of the `axis` environment of `tikzfigure`).

I have read a few related questions (the closest is [Passing a macro to a vector declaration in tikz/pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300815/passing-a-macro-to-a-vector-declaration-in-tikz-pgf) but I failed to make the accepted solution work for my case). I suppose the issue is that LateX expands macros as it reads them (correct me if I'm wrong) which means that `\begin{someenvironment}[option1=\mymacro]` will try to pass the string `\mymacro` to `option1` (and not care that it starts with a backslash, or care too late).

I roughly understand how the `\foo\bar` syntax is fixed by `\expandafter\foo\bar` but I could not get any similar trick to work, no matter how much of `\begin{axis}[xticklabels=` I prefaced with expandafters -

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 


\begin{document}

    %The figure I want to obtain (but without giving "A1,A2,A3" explicitly)
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=10,
    ymin=0,ymax=4,
    xtick={1,4,7},
    xticklabels={A1,A2,A3},
    ytick=\empty
    ]

    \addplot+[domain=0:10,samples=100,no markers]{sqrt(x)};

    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

    % This fails to do what I want, as the commas are not understood as value separators
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\tiklist}{A1,A2,B}
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=10,
    ymin=0,ymax=4,
    xtick={1,4,7},
    xticklabels={\tiklist},
    ytick=\empty
    ]

    \addplot+[domain=0:10,samples=100,no markers]{sqrt(x)};

    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compilation output: two figures]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can force expansion via the `.expanded` handler of pgfkeys (section 82.4.6 "Expanded and Multiple Values", p. 890, pgfmanual, v3.0.1a).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\tiklist}{A1,A2,B}
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=10,
    ymin=0,ymax=4,
    xtick={1,4,7},
    xticklabels/.expanded=\tiklist,
    ytick=\empty
    ]

    \addplot+[domain=0:10,samples=100,no markers]{sqrt(x)};

    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) This should be the preffered way, all in Ti*k*Z syntax!

Comment: Agreed.  While DC's answer will work in non-TikZ contexts, I understand what this one does, and it makes for much cleaner code.

Answer (score 8):

You can force expansion via:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 


\begin{document}

    %The figure I want to obtain (but without giving "A1,A2,A3" explicitly)
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=10,
    ymin=0,ymax=4,
    xtick={1,4,7},
    xticklabels={A1,A2,A3},
    ytick=\empty
    ]

    \addplot+[domain=0:10,samples=100,no markers]{sqrt(x)};

    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

    % This fails to do what I want, as the commas are not understood as value separators
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\tiklist}{A1,A2,B}
    \edef\tmp{\noexpand\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=10,
    ymin=0,ymax=4,
    xtick={1,4,7},
    xticklabels={\tiklist},
    ytick=\empty
    ]}\tmp

    \addplot+[domain=0:10,samples=100,no markers]{sqrt(x)};

    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What happened to `\begin{picture}...\end{picture}` ??

Comment: Looks like dark magic to me, but hey, it works. Thanks!